# Is Tsunkatse modeled on a real world martial arts?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In Star Trek: Voyager there is an episode called Tsunkatse (hope I didn't butcher it). In this episode we see a form of blood sport using some kind of martial arts.

My question is if this fighting style is just something made up on the fly or does it have basis in our world’s martial arts?

Comment: Each of the characters use a different fighting style. The game is called Tsunkatse, but the style is "mixed martial arts".

Comment: so its similar to our own MMA then? go into a ring and use whatever style you can to win over your opponent but do remember to hit the glowing disk spots on the body for more pain?

Comment: When Seven fights, she doesn't use the same style as the rest of the fighters. The implication seems to be that you can use whatever fighting style you like

Comment: @Valorum No, it's specifically stated in the episode (when J.G. Hertzler as the Hirogen is training Seven) that there are specific rules to Tsunkatse and that there is a list of allowed moves.

Comment: @Hans - The Hirogen who trains her is very much of the opinion that the Book of Tsunkatse is gonna get you killed if you try to follow it.

Comment: @Valorum True, but when Seven poses in a traditional defence and the Hirogen knocks her down she tells him "that was not one of the 33 sanctioned manoeuvres". So there are rules but apparently fighters are allowed to break/ignore them. Well, it *is* all about money.